# Force Create Record Not working in SLDS Modal

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds

I am using SLDS Modal.In modal window there is one button called continue and on the click of that I want to open the create record page.What I can see is on the button client side controller code the `$A.get("e.force:createRecord")` is not working.It is coming as undefined

Is it like `$A.get("e.force:createRecord")` doesn't work in modal window?

Comment: When you say "window" do you mean a new browser window? The SLDS [Modals](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/) would normally be used in the same window (and therefore JavaScript context) as the rest of the page.

Comment: It is not a new browser window.It is the same window.